# Encrypting passwords in WinForms app.config, .NET

Tags: .net, encryption

I want to store a password in a config file but i would like it to be encrypted so that in the app it can be read, decrypted and used. What's the best way to encrypt a password like this?
Edit:  I want to encrypt only password, not whole config, or whole section.

Answer (score 8):

[Encrypting Passwords in a .NET app.config File](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx)

Comment: but this works only on my computer! i mean: if i encrypt the password on my computer, the other user that gets the app installed is not able to decrypt the password and therefore to use my application

Comment: @agnieszka you could make the setting machine specific and allow each user to have their own settings,  since we are usually looking at passwords here it is probably a good thing that everyone does not have the ability to read the passwords if they could simply run it on their machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DpapiProtectedConfigurationProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.dpapiprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx)

See this links .

[Encrypting .NET configuration files through code](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/encrypting-net-configuration-files-through-code/)

[Implementing Protected Configuration With Windows Apps](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/ProtectedConfigWinApps.aspx)

[Encrypting Passwords in a .NET app.config File](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx)

Bye.