# What is best way to securely store a password in the properties.settings file?

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encrypting passwords in WinForms app.config, .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392876/encrypting-passwords-in-winforms-app-config-net)

I want to be able store username/password pair for a login box.  Each time the application is loaded, the saved credentials are loaded from the Properties.Settings file and then the login box is populated with these values.

I know there is always the chance that the password could be hacked, but anything must be better than storing clear-text in the properties.settings file.

I've been looking at using SecureString, but all that appears to do is prevent the password from being stored in cleartext in memory.

Any ideas the best way to handle this?

Comment: Why can't you just use the built-in password storage mechanisms that Windows provides?

Comment: Do you control he application you are logging on to?

Comment: Basically a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392876/encrypting-passwords-in-winforms-app-config-net

Comment: This is like asking "what's the most secure way to put a gold brick in a cardboard box in the middle of a field?" The question you should be asking is "what's the most secure way to store a gold brick with respect to the following attacks..." If you've already decided to use an insecure store, there's no point in making it more secure, and unless you can enumerate the attacks, it's not possible to design a more secure solution. Do not ask a security question without **stating the attacks you seek to defend against**.

Comment: @Eric, love the analogy! I guess the app.config is stored per user account, so its only as secure as anything else if the person has left their machine on. Question is then: do I really need to secure it or am I over thinking this/over paranoid about security?

Comment: You are not overthinking it; there is no such thing as overthinking a security problem. You are absolutely right to think very hard about how you are going to safely store the user's password. My point is that you should not start with the assumption that you're going to store the password *at all*.  If you are going to store the password or the password equivalent, then you should (1) enumerate the threats to the user by your doing so, and (2) consider using the standard password store technologies provided for you rather than making up your own.

Comment: What are the standard password store technologies you mention? I'd be interested to know how other apps handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why hashes are mentioned; if they are designed to be irreversible, how could they be used to pre-populate the fields?

When I did something similar to this a while ago, I did the following:

```
AES_encrypt ( username + saltString1 + password + saltString2 )
```

Store the result of that and store the AES key.

To populate the fields:

- recall the data and the key
- decrypt the data, using the key
- split the string about `saltString1`
- the first value of the split is the username
- the second value is `password + saltString2`

  - substring using `saltString2` and you have your password

Comment: Yes, this has nothing to do with hashing, its preventing storage of the password in clear text in the app.config file.

Comment: So now the password is encrypted, and the AES key is not. I suppose one could encrypt that too and say "it's turtles all the way down", but it has to end somewhere and that means that anyone who *has* the code can get the password as easily *as* the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can store just hash of password, instead saving plain text. Then, when you are comparing password stored in user database and password entered, you are comparing hashes instead of open text. Look in System.Security.Cryptography ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the login box to be prepopulated with the password, then it has to be stored in clear text *somewhere*, whether as a literal string in the source, a database, a config or settings file, or as a string in a compiled resource.

Also note that extracting a password from a masked password field can be as simple as sending a message to the textbox.

You might consider encrypting the password, or generating an MD5 hash and storing *that*. When the user logs in, use the same process as you used on the original password and compare the result to see if the correct password was entered, but that won't let you prepopulate the login box.

On the other hand, what's the point in requiring a password if you're going to populate the dialog? You may as well just show a form that says "press enter to log in" with no fields at all.

Comment: Because they have the option of clicking/unclicking 'Remember Me' checkbox, so next time it should remember their password when the app starts. If authentication succeeds, the password stored in their settings file will be used and the login won't even show. I still need to store password somewhere. I just thought it'd be nice to make it a little more secure.